# Does ViewSets generate view_names in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to use HyperlinkedIdentityField in my serializer, that's why I need view name. How can I get the view name if I need model_name-list for example?

Here is my serializer:

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
posts = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='', format=None)
class Meta:
    model = Category
    fields = ('url', 'category_name', 'id', 'parent', 'posts')
```

This is my views.py:

```
class PostViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
queryset = Post.objects.all()
serializer_class = PostSerializer
```

And here is my urls.py:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'categories', views.CategoryViewSet)
router.register(r'posts', views.PostViewSet)


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
]
```

My models:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    post_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    post_text = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    categories = models.ManyToManyField('Category', related_name='posts')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.post_name

class Category(models.Model):
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
    return self.category_name
```

I need a view_name for post-list, in order to use HyperlinkedIdentityField

Comment: too less information. Add the code snippet and then explain the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the Documentation for routers in DRF (http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/) says, if the base_name argument is not passed when registering the ViewSet then the view_name is auto generated depending on the queryset attribute of the ViewSet registered while defining the router.

In your case the view_name should be 'post-list' for the list view and 'post-detail' for the detail view of the viewset unless you want to change/override it by passing it as the third parameter to router.register().

Also note that the queryset attribute should always be present if you are not initializing the base_name for the ViewSet which otherwise will throw an error.

Comment: After using the view_name I have the following error "Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "post-list". You may have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on this field."

Comment: As you are referring to a particular instance of a post, You need to use "post-detail" as the view_name value to correctly map the post object. Also since category and post are M2M connected, is there a reason you have used HyperlinkIdentityField, instead of a ManyRelatedField?